# Get Data size on RKRequest/RKRequestQueue?

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using RestKit and it is great. 
I have few RKRequests gathered in one RKRequestQueue, and i wish to show the users the download progress.
I can not find a away to get or generate the data size of the requests.

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks 
Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently RKRequest's delegate has new method called
request:didReceivedData:totalBytesReceived:totalBytesExpectedToReceive:

You can implement this method to display download progress.

Checkout docs here:
[RKRequestDelegate docs...](http://restkit.org/api/0.9/Protocols/RKRequestDelegate.html#//api/name/request%3adidReceivedData%3atotalBytesReceived%3atotalBytesExectedToReceive%3a)

(documentation has typo in method name - I didn't check if it's correct in source code)

Comment: Thanks i was looking at old documentation.